# Tailwind custom classes in base layer not applying

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a `typography.css` file with code such as:

```
@layer base {
  .p {
    @apply font-light;
  }

  .p.subheading {
    @apply font-normal;
  }

  .p.xxl {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .p.xl {
    font-size: 1.375rem;
  }
}
```

For example.

In my `post.css` file, I apply classes to items inside a `.post`:

```
.post {
  h1,
  h2 {
    @apply p xxl subheading;
  }
  h3,
  h4 {
    @apply p xl subheading;
  }

  p {
    @apply p;
  }
  ul {
    @apply p list-disc list-inside;
  }
  p strong {
    @apply p subheading;
  }
}
```

However, the generated code applies the font-weight of the `p` and not the `subheading` and I must use `font-normal` for it to work. Additionally, no matter what I do, I cannot get the `font-size` to be reflected by `@apply`ing my custom class.

My `app.css` file includes them in the following order:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

@import "base/typography.postcss";

@import "parts/post.postcss";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the docs about Tailwind layers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-base-styles) carefully. When looking at your code, here are my suggestions:

1. The base layer is meant to override default styles of basic plain HTML elements (you are defining new CSS classes here).
2. However, the components layer is a good place for additional classes such as `.post`
3. You gave your files a `.postcss` file extension in your `app.css`. In case this wasn't intentional, you might want to remove that completely or give it a `.css` extension.

That being said, I would organize your code like this:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";

@layer components {
  .post h1,
  .post h2 {
    @apply text-2xl font-normal;
  }
  .post h3,
  .post h4 {
    @apply text-xl font-normal;
  }

  .post p {
    @apply font-light;
  }
  .post ul {
    @apply font-light list-disc list-inside;
  }
  .post p strong {
    @apply font-normal;
  }
}

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Of course you can put the `.post` rules into a separate file. Also [this is a good read](https://bloggie.io/@kinopyo/organize-your-css-in-the-tailwind-style-with-layer-directive) about that topic of organizing your CSS with Tailwind.

Hope this helps or at least gives some pointers.